# Какие ошибки присутствуют в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"Дети и даже взрослые всё чаще отдают предпочтение компьютерным играм, как средству для снятия стресса". Подскажите, есть ли в данном предложении пунктуационные или иные ошибки.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Есть: лишняя запятая.

> Дети и даже взрослые всё чаще отдают предпочтение компьютерным играм как средству для снятия стресса.

Когда значение союза *как* 'в качестве', запятая перед ним не ставится.